# Next.js 13.x App Router Internationalization with Nested Layouts

Tags: typescript, next.js, internationalization, next.js13, i18next

I'm working on a Next.js 13 project with the new `/app` folder routing, and attempting to set up internationalization. My project structure looks like this:

[image]

1. **Root AppLayout** (src/app/[lang]/layout.tsx)

This component receives a `lang` props parameter from its route and uses it to fetch a language-specific dictionary (`i18nDictionary`). The challenge I'm facing is to pass this `i18nDictionary` to the children of this component because there we can find my actual components.

```
import React from 'react';
import { getI18nDictionary } from '@/i18n';

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: {
    lang: string;
  };
};

const AppLayout = async ({ children, params }: Props) => {
  const i18nDictionary = await getI18nDictionary(params.lang);

  return (
    <html lang={params.lang}>
      <body>
        {children}
        {i18nDictionary.home.hero.title}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default AppLayout;
```

Have a look at `{i18nDictionary.home.hero.title}`, that works. I just need to pass the `i18nDictionary` down to the pipeline.

2. **Child AppLayout** (src/app/[lang]/(main)/layout.tsx)

Here are my actual components, which means I have to get this information here one way or another.

```
import React from 'react';
import type { Metadata } from 'next/types';

import { InitializeChakra } from '@/components/InitializeChakra';
import { Header } from '@/components/Header';
import { Footer } from '@/components/Footer';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Test',
  description: 'Test',
  keywords: 'test',
};

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const AppLayout = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return (
    <InitializeChakra>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </InitializeChakra>
  );
};

export default AppLayout;
```

3. **i18nDictionary** (src/i18n/index.tsx)

Here's my internationalization logic:

```
import { DEFAULT_LOCALE, type SUPPORTED_LOCALES } from '@/middleware';

export type I18nDictionary = {
  [page: string]: {
    [section: string]: {
      [element: string]: string;
    };
  };
};

export type I18nDictionaryGetter = () => Promise<I18nDictionary>;

const i18nDictionaries: {
  [K in (typeof SUPPORTED_LOCALES)[number]]: I18nDictionaryGetter;
} = {
  en: () => import('./en.json').then((module) => module.default),
  bg: () => import('./bg.json').then((module) => module.default),
};

export async function getI18nDictionary(
  locale: string,
): Promise<I18nDictionary> {
  return (i18nDictionaries[locale] || i18nDictionaries[DEFAULT_LOCALE])();
}
```

### Question:

How can I pass the `i18nDictionary` from the **Root AppLayout** component to its children props, so that I can use it within the **Child AppLayout** components, e.g. `<Header />`?

```
'use client';

import {
  Box,
  Flex,
  Container,
  Stack,
  useDisclosure,
  IconButton,
  useColorModeValue,
  Icon,
  useColorMode,
  Heading,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { CloseIcon, HamburgerIcon, SunIcon, MoonIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';
import Link from 'next/link';

import { Logo } from '@/components/Logo';
import { TextUnderline } from '@/components/TextUnderline';
import { MobileNav } from '@/components/Header/MobileNav';
import { DesktopNav } from '@/components/Header/DesktopNav';

export const Header = () => {
  const { isOpen: isMobileNavOpen, onToggle } = useDisclosure();
  const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode();

  return (
    <Box as="header">
      <Flex
        as={'header'}
        pos="fixed"
        top="0"
        w={'full'}
        minH={'60px'}
        boxShadow={'sm'}
        zIndex="999"
        justify={'center'}
        css={{
          backdropFilter: 'saturate(180%) blur(5px)',
          backgroundColor: useColorModeValue('rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)', 'rgba(26, 32, 44, 0.8)'),
        }}
      >
        <Container as={Flex} maxW={'7xl'} align={'center'}>
          <Flex
            flex={{ base: '0', md: 'auto' }}
            ml={{ base: -2 }}
            mr={{ base: 6, md: 0 }}
            display={{ base: 'flex', md: 'none' }}
          >
            <IconButton
              onClick={onToggle}
              icon={isMobileNavOpen ? <CloseIcon w={3} h={3} /> : <HamburgerIcon w={5} h={5} />}
              variant={'ghost'}
              size={'sm'}
              aria-label={'Toggle Navigation'}
            />
          </Flex>

          <Flex flex={{ base: 1, md: 'auto' }} justify={{ base: 'start', md: 'start' }}>
            <Stack
              href="/"
              direction="row"
              alignItems="center"
              spacing={{ base: 2, sm: 4 }}
              as={Link}
            >
              <Icon as={Logo} w={{ base: 8 }} h={{ base: 8 }} />
              <Heading as={'h1'} fontSize={'xl'} display={{ base: 'none', md: 'block' }}>
                <TextUnderline>Quant</TextUnderline> Logistics
              </Heading>
            </Stack>
          </Flex>

          <Stack
            direction={'row'}
            align={'center'}
            spacing={{ base: 6, md: 8 }}
            flex={{ base: 1, md: 'auto' }}
            justify={'flex-end'}
          >
            <DesktopNav display={{ base: 'none', md: 'flex' }} />
            <IconButton
              size={'sm'}
              variant={'ghost'}
              aria-label={'Toggle Color Mode'}
              onClick={toggleColorMode}
              icon={colorMode == 'light' ? <SunIcon /> : <MoonIcon />}
            />
          </Stack>
        </Container>
      </Flex>
      <MobileNav isOpen={isMobileNavOpen} />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

### middleware.ts

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { match } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher';
import Negotiator from 'negotiator';

export const DEFAULT_LOCALE = 'en';
export const SUPPORTED_LOCALES = ['en', 'bg'];

export const middleware = (request: NextRequest) => {
  // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  const pathnameHasLocale = SUPPORTED_LOCALES.some(
    (locale: string) => pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) || pathname === `/${locale}`,
  );
  if (pathnameHasLocale) return;

  // Redirect if there is no locale
  const negotiatorHeaders: Negotiator.Headers = {};
  request.headers.forEach((value, key) => {
    negotiatorHeaders[key] = value;
  });
  const languages = new Negotiator({
    headers: negotiatorHeaders,
  }).languages();
  const locale = match(languages, SUPPORTED_LOCALES, DEFAULT_LOCALE);

  // e.g. incoming request is /products
  // The new URL is now /en/products
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${locale}/${pathname}`, request.url));
};

export const config = {
  // Skip all internal paths (_next)
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)'],
};
```

Comment: I was facing same issue, i had to pass to all my sub components, so without wasting time i switched to page router because i didn't found any good solution.

Comment: @YashParekh, that's sad :(

Comment: @YashParekh, have you looked at https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router-client-components

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using react context api, you can create an `I18nContext` that provides the `i18nDictionary` components of application that needs it

> This usually known as prop drill avoiding solutions

Example:
Provider part:

`src/app/[lang]/layout.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { I18nContext } from '@/contexts/I18nContext';

const AppLayout = async ({ children, params }: Props) => {
  const i18nDictionary = await getI18nDictionary(params.lang);

  return (
    <I18nContext.Provider value={i18nDictionary}>
      <html lang={params.lang}>
        <body>
          {children}
        </body>
      </html>
    </I18nContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AppLayout;
```

Consumer part:

`// src/components/Header.tsx`

```
import { useI18n } from '@/contexts/I18nContext';

export const Header = () => {
  const i18nDictionary = useI18n();
  ...
};
```

The component:

`// src/contexts/I18nContext.tsx`

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

export const I18nContext = createContext(null);

export const useI18n = () => useContext(I18nContext);
```